# No textures showed In Material Preview and Render Preview Models but pure black color

Tags: shaders

After in Shader Edior plugging a image texture into the charactor's Face, i went to Sculpt Mode to adjust the charactor's Body. But when i selected the Face again and turned Display in Solid Mode into Material Preview and Render Preview Models, i had nothing but pure black color.
My Blender version is 3.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Did you create an image texture set to black color? Unfortunately your screenshot doesn't show your full material setup, but since there is no color showing next to _Base Color_ in the _Principled BSDF_ I would suspect there is an image texture plugged in... and since the default "New Image" dialogue creates a blank, black image I suppose that's what you plugged in there. I mean, you literally wrote you added a texture in the _Shader Editor_, so maybe you should find out how this texture looks like.